# Discord Command Permissions

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was creating a admins commands for my discord bot. I know how to know code bans command thing. but I want to make sure that this command only  admins permission can use it.Can someone show me how to do it? thanks. Here my codes

```js
client.on('message', async message =>{
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content === "ban"){
    message.channel.send("Users Have been banned, lol")
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that [`Client#message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) is deprecated. Use [`Client#messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GuildMember.permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions)

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) return;
  if (message.content === "ban") {
    message.channel.send("Users Have been banned, lol")
  }
})
```

You can send an information message in the `return` statement:

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) return message.channel.send("You need permissions!");
```

You can choose any permission with [`Permissions.FLAGS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

Comment: Hmm I'm gonna try that

Comment: Its work! thanks you so much. but if you are not busy can you help me for other problems?. I have admin perm. but it say you have no permissions. can you help me?